# While schedule below script through crontab receive incorrect output date format is going wrong

Tags: linux, cron, scripting, shell-scripting, unix-shell

```
PFB script
dd=$(perl -e 'use POSIX;print strftime "%Y%m%d",localtime time-172800;')

Date=$(perl -e 'use POSIX;print strftime "%d%m%Y",localtime time-172800;')

for i in `cat /path/Path_CDR.txt`
do
cd $i
compress event*$dd*.asn
compress event*$dd*.CDR
zcat event*$dd* |grep Event |awk -F "," '{print $14,$16}'|awk -F '"' '{print $2","$4","'$Date'}' >>/path/abc$Date.txt

done
```

Output1:
Script run manually using sh -x (script name) output comes in as per below format(Coorect)

```
07923243305,14,4112019
07923241717,44,4112019
07923224727,33,4112019
07923241717,10,4112019
```

while schedule on crontab the output comes in below format only date format issue(date issue  4.11202e+06)

```
07923243305,14,4.11202e+06
07923241717,44,4.11202e+06
07923224727,33,4.11202e+06
07923241717,10,4.11202e+06
```

Kindly help me with this

Answer (score 0):

most likely your locale variables are not in cron environment.

check the values of LANG* and LC_* in your shell env and set them explicitly at the beginning of your script, e.g. I have

```
[alex@alex ~]$ set | grep ^LANG
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
[alex@alex ~]$ set | grep ^LC_
```

so I would put an

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

at the beginnning of the script